# 'import hid' in Python results in error "hid.so: undefined symbol: libusb_open"

Tags: python, usb, cython, libusb

I'm trying to install cython-hidapi to read a USB on my [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin). I've followed the instructions from *[cython-hidapi](https://github.com/gbishop/cython-hidapi)* and installed the following versions:

- lib-usb == 1.0.9
- hidapi == 0.7.0
- cython == 0.16
- python == 2.7
- cython-hidapi == latest checkout

When I execute the test part from the installation (python > import hid), I receive the following error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hid
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hid.so: undefined symbol: libusb_open
```

Why do I receive this error and what can I check / do about it?

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hid.so` to show what libraries are linked to hid.so, it will report if the expected libraries are not found.  Then use the `nm` utility to print the symbols of libusb library.  Does the `nm` output show a libusb_open symbol present?

Comment: ldd shows the following:
ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hid.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7d5ff000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb3c88f5000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb3c8538000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb3c8d3b000)

nm libusb continas libusb_open:
0000000000003b50 T libusb_open

Comment: I'm guessing.  Did the setup.py run ok?  Looking at https://github.com/gbishop/cython-hidapi/blob/master/setup.py, it may be that the `LDFLAGS` don't match your platform and so the build fails.  `setup.py` appears to be set up for i386 architecture, you're using `x86-64`.  Try changing `setup.py` to match the library paths for your arch.

Comment: The setup did, strangely enough, not give any errors. You were right about the wrong architecture. I've changed it and re-installed the package. Sadly enough I still receive the same error :-(.

Comment: This is a linker problem. I suppose libusb_open lives in libusb to which you are linking. But setup is writen poorly and links explicitly with usb-1.0. First you have to find what version of libusb installed at you machine and where its so lies. Then you have to correct include(-I) and libs (-L) path in setup.py and run build. Also you way want to try setting runtime library search path like so: python <code>setup.py --rpath /to_where/libusb_so/lives build</code> Or setting it using before you run python like so <code>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/libusb_so/lives</code> bt this is poor method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with this exact same issue over the past week. Luckily one of my friends that knows the Cython world quite well was able to help. You need to change the setup(...) function in setup.py as follows:

```
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("hid", ["hid.pyx", "hid-libusb.c"],
                  libraries=["usb-1.0", "udev", "rt"])]
)
```

I don't know whether there will be slight variances on other distributions, but this has been tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 0.1.12. Use the suggestions in reply to your original post to determine the correct linker flags (LDFLAGS) and for the `libraries=` line.

A [pull request](https://github.com/gbishop/cython-hidapi/pull/4) have been submitted to the maintainer. You can also get the change from my [fork](https://github.com/parautenbach/cython-hidapi).

Comment: The linker (using `gcc`) is sensitive to the order in which libraries are specified. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gcc.1.html):

`It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.`

Comment: You can also check this [layman's explanation](http://blog.gnucom.cc/2012/linking-why-order-matters/).